# Where does this oil filter gasket go?

Tags: motorcycle, kawasaki, oil-filter

I'm doing an oil change on my 2009 Kawasaki Ninja (250cc). In the new oil filter package there are two gaskets: one large one (goes on the bottom of oil filter tray), and one small one.

I'm not quite sure where the small one goes... any ideas? I didn't see a small one on the old filter. Should I just leave it off?

(gaskets shown at bottom of image)

[image]

Comment: What is the displacement of your Ninja?  How many cc's?

Comment: Updated post (250cc)

Comment: Also, what is the part number and brand of the oil filter you purchased?

Comment: FRAM Model#: CH6012

Answer (score 4):

Found it... [image: faq.ninja250.org/images/d/d9/4Winterize.jpg]

The small O-Ring goes where the oil filter bolt meets the oil-filter tray.

Comment: Award yourself the answer too!   :-)

Comment: how do you call this tool ? looks very handy !